# How to insert multiple select option in PHP MySQL when multiple='multiple' is enabled

Tags: php, mysql

I have a FORM with method POST. In the form I have two select drop-down with multiple='multiple' enabled in both so that user can make multiple selections.

Now I am using MySQL database to store data.

I am using foreach loop to iterate all the selections made.

Here is the image Select drop-down image

[image]

My code

```
$cid = $row['cid'];
$work_location = $_POST['work_location'];
$interest = $_POST['interest'];

foreach ($work_location as $value) {
    $work = $value;
}

foreach ($interest as $value) {
    $int = $value;
}

$insert_oth_data = "INSERT INTO resume_spec_data
                            (cid, work_location, interest) 
                    VALUES('$cid', '$work', '$int')";
mysqli_query($con, $insert_oth_data);

echo var_export($work_location);
echo var_export($interest);
echo var_export($work);
echo var_export($int);

echo var_export( $insert_oth_data );
```

Here work_location and interest are the fields that will carry the multiple select values. I don't want to use implode function because it will make data extraction difficult as table grows. I want to store the values in saperate rows of database.

The problem I am facing is that data is being inserted, but the problem is when I select multiple options only one data is being inserted not all.

The result I get after inserting the data is:

```
array ( 0 => 'Delhi', 1 => 'NCR', )array ( 0 => 'Software development', 1 => 'Business analyst', 2 => 'Web development', )'NCR''Web development''INSERT INTO resume_spec_data(cid, work_location, interest) VALUES(\'1\', \'NCR\', \'Web development\')'
```

As you can compare from the image I have made multiple selections. But single data is being taken here

For reference

```
$work_location contains array ( 0 => 'Delhi', 1 => 'NCR', )

$interest contains 

array ( 0 => 'Software development', 
        1 => 'Business analyst', 
        2 => 'Web development', 
)
```

$work contains NCR

$int contains Web development only

$work and $int should also contains same as $work_location and $interest respectively.

One thing that I found here is that I have applied Insert query outside the foreach loop maybe that is why only one value is being taken. Since I am using multiple select drop-down here with multiple='multiple' enabled, I don't know how to do this to achieve the result I want.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: for starters you code is **vulnerable** to **sql ijection** use only **prepared statemenst with parameters**. second you need norlized database, where you have a second table for the interests that you got and tehn you need a table that connect user with the inetrest table, so that you save only the id of the interest in normalized manner

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: And then you are looping over the arrays completely independantly of doing anything with the individual occurances in those arrays. So your INSERT will only ever SEE the last occurance in each array

Comment: I know this is vulnerable to sql injection. Currently I am trying to just insert the data. Also my table has only 3 fields, [cid, work_location, interest] to store data. I think inserting work-location in one table and interest in other will be hectic to do.

Comment: "single data is being taken"...yes, because the INSERT command happens _once_, and it occurs after your loops have all finished. So in the loops you're pointlessly re-assigning new values to the same variable, and then discarding them again without using them. It's fairly basic logic - if you wait until after a loop has finished, then you can't use the values which are present when the loop is running. You'll only ever see the last one which was assigned in the last run of the loop. It's unclear how you ever imagined this would be able to work successfully.

Comment: " know this is vulnerable to sql injection"...then please fix it now so that you don't have to re-write and re-test all the SQL-related code again once you've got it "working" the first time. That would be a big waste of effort, especially when you're already aware  of the problem and understand how to fix it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly can you please suggest me the correct code sample.

Comment: @ADyson Yes I know this but I don't know how to include the insert query because I have 2 different foreach loop can you please suggest me the correct code

Comment: Yes! NEST the loops and move the INSERT into the inner loop. Prepare the query first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `INSERT` command happens once, and it occurs after your loops have all finished. So in the loops you're pointlessly re-assigning new values to the same variable, and then discarding them again without using them. Obviously if you wait until after a loop has finished, then you can't use the values which are present when the loop is running. You'll only ever see the last one which was assigned in the last run of the loop.

And you've explained that you're struggling to fix this because you don't know how to include the insert query inside the loops, because there are 2 different foreach loops.

---

So really I think the root cause here is that your database structure is flawed. It seems you permit different numbers of values in your form (e.g. 2 entries for work locations, then 3 entries for domains of interest, per your screenshot), and there's no particular relationship between them (e.g. does "Delhi" belong with "software development, or "business analyst", or the other one? There's no logic to explain that).

And yet, you're trying to store them in a table which inherently relates them together by storing them next to each other in rows. This will result in poor data quality because a) there's no way to decide which belongs with which, and b) if you have different numbers of entries in each field then you'll end up with gaps.

You need separate tables to store each list - one table for locations, and one table for interests, both with the Cid to link them to the master record.

This will then make it easy to use the data in you loops e.g.

```
foreach ($work_location as $value) {
    $work = $value;
    //...write query code to insert into work locations table
}

foreach ($interest as $value) {
    $int = $value;
    //...write query code to insert into interests table
}
```

Comment: Yes I did that by creating 2 separate tables. Now data is being inserted. Thanks